# Nginx rewrite unencodes url

Tags: nginx

It seems Nginx it always un-encodes urls when used with a regular expression. I have a rewrite rule:

```
location /api/ {
    rewrite /api/(.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/$1;
}
```

I would like to remove the api from the usl but keep the rest of the path. Part of the path is an email address someone@somewhere.com. I am passing someone%40somewhere.com but Nginx is turning it back with the @ sign.

Answer (score 6):

The correct answer seem to be

```
location /api/ {
        rewrite ^ $request_uri;
        rewrite ^/api/(.*) $1 break;
        return 400;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/$uri;
    }
```

See [Nginx pass_proxy subdirectory without url decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684300/nginx-pass-proxy-subdirectory-without-url-decoding/37584637#37584637) for full answer and original author.

(I realize this question is older than the one I referenced but I found this in google search and may not be the last one, so ...)

Answer (score 2):

That is how Nginx handles urls. You can bypass it by changing your web application to escape the "%" character as "%25" and pass `someone%2540somewhere.com`.

This will be unescaped as `someone%40somewhere.com`.